# B1D popscreen from Schoeps

Tags: podium, live-sound, plosives

Has anyone used the B1D as a close-speech pop guard for their Schoeps microphones?

http://www.schoeps.de/en/products/b1d

I am specifically going to test it out with an MK41.

I need something that can withstand close pops by otherwise untrained speakers, at podiums for corporate events.

Nothing makes those executives turn around and glare at the sound mixer (me) at one of these events than a nice big POP (BOOOOOOMMMM) throughout the hotel's auditorium. I'd like more than anything to reply to them "It's your buddy up there - he doesn't know how to speak into a microphone correctly" but I don't think that will go over too well - they might not let me have any cannolis or pastries at the refreshment table (and you don't want that to happen... the continental breakfasts at these places consist of dried bacon, egg molds and yoplait yogurt!).

Any advice on a close-speech pop guard (that also looks good on camera) please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the B1D in a close micing situation, but I have used the Shure outdoor windscreen designed for the SM81 (which fits the SM57 (see your Pres. Obama and every president going back to Bush and beyond). It's quite big, but very effective, even outdooors in calm conditions. It fits the Schoeps MK41/Mk4 very well. You might want to put an O-ring on the mic body just below the capsule to ensure a snug fit.
Oh, yeah, its pretty cheap too, around $50 as I recall.
cheers,
Chris Newton

Answer (score 1):

The B1D looks like it is well designed--the air space between the foam and the mic end should help. (Shure's indoor pop filter for the SM-57 works the same way and is effective.)  Sorry, haven't had the chance to try out the B1D, but it should certainly be better than not using a pop screen.